# End to end testing framework for C++ application

Tags: c++, c, linux, testing, automated-tests

I am testing a C/C++ application. For the majority of methods I was able to write unit tests using CppUTest.
But there are a few for which not, and I want to write integration/end to end tests to test these methods too.
What I want to test whether

- correct output file is generated
- for invalud arguments proper error messages are printed (it is a command line tool)
- it displays correct output messgaes

My question is whether there are tools for this, or should I write some scripts to invoke my application, capture output etc.? If yes, how to start these scripts? Invoke them from CppUtest?

Comment: @close- and downvoters: "Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it." I think I have described it. I do not want a specific software recommendation, instead - having no experience - I am curious what others do in such a situation.

Comment: As we've just had a similar situation, allow me please this friendly note. I know sometimes it might be frustrating, but whether we like the rules of this site or not, as users we have to follow them. They are not made by one person, but by the whole community, and are heavily discussed on meta. Everyone, including you and me, is allowed to take part in the discussions and contribute to them. But at the end of the day, it is the community who decides. So, please inform yourself what is OK and what not, and stick to it. By saying this, I intend no offence to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know several ways to test for correct output:

If you use CMake and CTest, you can use CTest to compare the output of your program with the expected output. Does only work for text output (as screen output normally is), and will not work if you output random numbers of time/date and stuff like that. Look for add_test_output_check() in the CMake manuel.

If your program does not write hard-coded to stdout, then you could pass an std::ostringstream and afterwards test the contents of the string using your preferred unit test framework.

Last but not least you could use dup2() to define other file descriptors for stdout and stderr, execute the test and at the end check the contents of the file(s).

For the output file, I guess you have to create a reference output file and then compare the contents of this file with the file that was generated by the test: Write a test function that loads both files and does a memcmp() on the data.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I don't find `add_test_output_check()` or similar items in the CMake manual. Could you please clarify?

Comment: Sorry, this is the name of my own macro. You need to look for `set_tests_properties()`.